# How to search ecommerce products from external (specific) websites on my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, search

I want a search box on my wordpress website where a user can search for products

then I want to submit this form to other(specific) websites and have the results display on my page.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Yes. Anything is possible, except time travel and dividing by zero. And we're not so sure about time travel. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry I am new in web development field. so this might be noob question.